# Angular - Deploying a JSON file to firebase

Tags: json, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**Summary**

- I have an angular project with a JSON file with mock data
- When I build the project, I stick the JSON file into the 'dist' folder
- I have an angular service which references the JSON file
- I deploy to firebase and receive an error
- Please excuse lack of knowledge here, exceptionally new to this

**Questions**

1. Is it possible to use a JSON file whilst working in LocalHost?
2. What have I done wrong with the deployment to firebase?

**Service**

```js
import { IProjects } from './projects.interface';

@Injectable()
export class ProjectsService {
    private _projectURL = '/dist/projects-list.json';

    constructor(private _http: Http) { }

    getProjects(): Observable<IProjects[]> {
        return this._http.get(this._projectURL)
            .map((response: Response) => <IProjects[]> response.json())
            .do(data => console.log('All: ' +  JSON.stringify(data)))
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    getProject(id: number): Observable<IProjects> {
        return this.getProjects()
            .map((projects: IProjects[]) => projects.find(p => p.projectId === id));
    }

    private handleError(error: Response) {
        console.error(error);
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
    }
}
```

**List Component that displays the list of projects**

```js
export class ProjectsListComponent implements OnInit {
    pageTitle = "Project List";
    errorMessage: string;
    projects: IProjects[];

    constructor(private _projectsService: ProjectsService) {

    }


    ngOnInit(): void {
        this._projectsService.getProjects()
            .subscribe(projects => this.projects = projects,
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    }

    onRatingClicked(message: string): void {
        this.pageTitle = 'Project List: ' + message;
    }
}
```

**Error Received in the browser**
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need add your mock json file in the `assets` folder in your angular project.

and  you can access like this

```
getProjects(): Observable<IProjects[]> {
        return this._http.get("assets/projects-list.json")
            .map((response: Response) => <IProjects[]> response.json())
            .do(data => console.log('All: ' +  JSON.stringify(data)))
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

Note:- you need add static file like image or config file in the assets folder. angular can only access assets folder.

Comment: Thanks @jonnysai! - I've tried that without much luck. However, when i run "ng build --watch" the json file is now appearing in the assets folder. I'm getting the same error when I deploy to firebase, and locally (localhost), it can't seem to find the file. ("Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: I dont know firebase but its should work locally. try ng serve

Comment: ahh, i've got it working both locally and on firebase. The url needs to be "assets/projects-list.json". If you update your answer with that I'll mark it as 'answered' as you've taught me something new there. Thank you for your time Jonny, much appreciated.

Comment: this._http.get("./projects-list.json") not working ? did you tried ?

Comment: Yup, it didn't work until I added 'assets/' to the front of it.

Comment: weird !! I am using similarly for my angular project and its working like charm. any how i updated my answer.